# Is it possible to make a modifiable copy of an unmodifiable map?

Tags: java, data-structures

**Description:**

One of my problem sets is provided with test cases to check if the typed code works correctly. I won't go into much detail, but basically these tests take a map as input. My code worked perfectly for all test cases except for one: when I took a look at the test, I saw that the input map gets changed into an unmodifiable map (*Collections.unmodifiableMap(numbers)*) and this unmodifiable map is passed on to the method that I wrote. This is the only test that does it, so I was wondering if it is possible to make a copy of this unmodifiable map such that it can be modified within my method? The most important modification that I'll have to make is updating the value of a key (*map.put(key, map.get(key)-1*).

**Extension:**

An additional question, are there similar ways to do this for other data structures such as Lists or Sets?

Comment: You can make a modifyable copy of the unmodifyable map, but any modification will only affect the modifyable copy and not the unmodifyable original.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: Your code is modifying the input and passes all the tests, but then another test passes an unmodifyable input. So, is your code _supposed_ to modify the input, or is that a side-effect that is unwanted and not checked for in the tests?

Comment: My code is definitely supposed to modify the input (turnpike reconstruction, backtracking), so I believe that it is just an error. Or is there a way to do this problem without modifying the input?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way is creating a new map:

```
final Map<?, ?> unmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>());
final Map<?, ?> modifiable = new HashMap<>(unmodifiable);
```

Both maps reference the *same* values.

**Extension**

For collections like lists and sets, it works similarly. They usually have constructors that you can pass another collection to.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to create a new List or Map to update the state of their objects.  It's the collections that are unmodifiable, not the objects in them.

```java
      List<Foo> mod = IntStream.range(1, 10).mapToObj(Foo::new).collect(
            Collectors.toList());
      List<Foo> unmod = Collections.unmodifiableList(mod);
      // unmod.add(new Foo(20)); <-- can't do this

      List<Foo> subList = unmod.subList(2, 4);
      //  subList.remove(0); <-- or this
      Foo f = unmod.get(3); 
      f.v = 99; // <-- but this is allowed
      System.out.println(unmod);


      class Foo {
          int v;

          Foo(int v) {
              this.v = v;
          }
          public String toString() {
              return v + "";
          }
       }
```